# Ubuntu 20.04 not starting after VirtualBox VirtualDisk resizing

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04

Since the virtual disk was too small I resized it via

**Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager → File → Virtual Media Manager**

After that the Ubuntu 20.04 Guest did not start any more (a short error message I do not remember followed by a blank screen)

I searched for a solution but the things I found looked old or strange to me.

How to fix this easily?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by inserting a Ubuntu 20.04 ISO-image and booted from CD.

Next increased the partitions with the "Disks" tool.

After that I installed the tool "Boot-Repair" and executed "Recommended repair".

Restarted the guest and it booted properly

Comment: Worked for me without "repair" part: resizing appeared to be enough